# Bengal/Maine Coon kitten: crying loudly/repeatedly

Tags: cats, behavior, vocalizations, separation-anxiety

I was recently given an 8-week old Bengal x Maine Coon mix kitten. Best guess is that the mix is 60% Bengal and 40% Maine Coon.

The kitten was crying **sharply/loudly/repeatedly** from the minute I first saw her in the previous owner's vehicle. And she is still crying now (4 days layer).

The cat literally does stop crying for a second, except to:

- Sleep
- When it's on my lap
- Or when other cats are around

I have to admit that the **crying is driving me absolutely nuts**. I can't force the other cats to hang around the kitten all the time. And I can't hold her in my lap all day, every day. So the crying continues!

From what I’ve read, the kitten is likely suffering from separation anxiety. But I’m not able to find much credible information about treating it/making the cat happy.

The kitten was checked over by a vet (four days ago) and was given a clean bill of health. She is eating, drinking, sleeping, defecating and urinating normally -- that is, after I hold her to calm her down.

Are there any proven techniques that could help the kitten stop crying (and preserve my sanity and hearing)?

Comment: 8 weeks is too young to be separated from her mother. Take her back to the breeder until she's 12-14 weeks old.

Comment: Did the litter have any other kittens? Maybe she misses (one of) his litter mates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to:

1. Keep it busy (aka quiet), when possible, by:

   - Letting it sit on people.
   - Be around other pets.
   - Tire it out via a mouse-on-a-stick toy.
2. When the above is not possible, put the cat in a room that is out of earshot (with all the amenities, of course). The cat will yell as much as it needs to, without driving people insane.
3. Eventually, the cat will lose it's voice. The cat can be brought back to a room that is within earshot at this point, because the yelling is much quieter, although still present.
4. After a few days, the cat will settle down and stop yelling altogether.